# how to get the row number of an item in the qlistwidget using Pyqt5 in python

Tags: python, pyqt5, row-number

How to get the row number of each item in the QlistWidget  i a able to get the text of the item but not the row number.

the expected result :

- current row ==> 1
- checkpath  Displayed Path => C:/Users/test/Downloads\cv.docx

**i don't know how to return the row number i tried the index but it return a wrong result.**

I think this is the line that must changed:

```
                print("current row ==> {} \n checkpath  Displayed Path => {}".format(index,self.fullPath))
```

where **index** is used in **enumarate**.

## code:

```
def checkPath(self,folder):         # Funtion to check the given path for the wanted extension (Files)

        try:
            directory=folder

            whichChecked=""
            for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):

                for index,filename in enumerate(files):
                    if len(self.lineEdit_Ext.text())>0:
                        self.lineEdit_Ext.setStyleSheet("background-color:white")
                        self.lineEdit_Ext.setPlaceholderText("Enter The Filetype Extention Here")

                        if filename.endswith(self.lineEdit_Ext.text()):
                            fullPath=os.path.join(root,filename)
                            print(fullPath)
                            self.fileList.append(fullPath)

                    elif self.rdBtn_docx.isChecked() and filename.endswith("docx") or filename.endswith("doc") :
                        self.fullPath=os.path.join(root,filename)

                        index = +1


                        print("current row ==> {} \n checkpath  Displayed Path => {}".format(index,self.fullPath))

                        print("=========================================")
                        self.fileList.append(self.fullPath)

                        whichChecked="docx - doc Ext was Selected"

                    if len(self.fileList) > 0:
                        self.lineEdit_Ext.setStyleSheet("bacground-color:white;")
                        self.lineEdit_Ext.setPlaceholderText("{0}".format(whichChecked))
                    else:
                        self.lineEdit_Ext.setStyleSheet("background-color:Red")
                        self.lineEdit_Ext.setPlaceholderText("No Ext is Specified")                            


            self.ListFilesInViewer(self.fileList)           # add the list into the  listWidgetPDFlist 


            return folder

        except Exception as e:
            print("this error occure {0}".format(e))
```

Answer (score 1):

> QListWidget.currentRow()
>
> Return type:   PySide.QtCore.int
>
> This property holds the row of the current item..

. . .

```
def FileListSelected(self): 
    """ Function to select the desired file from the list in the left pane """

    itemNumber = self.listWidgetPDFlist.currentRow()           # +++
    Item = self.listWidgetPDFlist.currentItem().text()
    print("this is the SELECTED file==>{}".format(Item))
    print("this is the itemNumber   ==>{}".format(itemNumber)) # +++
```

. . .

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer.

but what i want is not return the row number of the selected Item what i want is to once the user select the PATH and the QlistWidget is displayed the Items..i need to return each Item with its row number....

because after that i need to compare the row numbers when the user select one of the items.     so I think the statement must be done in the CheckPath function and not FileListSelected function.

Comment: the row number of the selected Item --->>> itemNumber

Comment: my question is not concern the selected Item... what i need is to print all the items in the QlistWidget with their row number.